# Nested for loop pandas dataframe does not create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, nested

I have this nested loop:

```
rolling=['10','20']

for i in range(len(ex)):
    for d in rolling:
       df = nested_df.loc[other_nested_df['pio'][i]:(other_nested_df['pio'][i]+10)].copy()
       ex.loc[i]['date_vert_'+str(d)=df['date'].iloc[-1]
```

The loop does not give any error but I cannot understand why at the end the dataframe `ex` does not have other two columns called `date_vert_10` and `date_vert_20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ex.loc[i][...]` to `ex.loc[i, ...]`:

```
rolling=['10','20']

for i in range(len(ex)):
    for d in rolling:
       df = nested_df.loc[other_nested_df['pio'][i]:(other_nested_df['pio'][i]+10)].copy()
       ex.loc[i, 'date_vert_'+str(d)=df['date'].iloc[-1]
       # ^^^^^^^^^^^ changed
```